# Can not Add() elements to page (IOS) xaml, gif image

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

Hello I'm trying to use FFImageloader package in XAML. I've added the custom renders in appdelegate and mainacticivy on the devices. When it renderes my page it throws an error.

I've tried to remove properties from the new namespace and it still throws this error. I have added the namespaces and installed the following packages from the guide on their github page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
     xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="ODEON.Pages.news"
xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
Title="MainWindow">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
        DownsampleToViewSize="true"
        Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">
    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
    <ListView x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding title.rendered}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

this is the error :

```
ODEON/Pages/news.xaml(10,10): Error: Position 9:10. Can not Add() elements to ODEON.Pages.news.Content (ODEON.iOS)
```

Comment: Content can only contain a single child element, you have two.- CachedImage and ListView.  You need to wrap them in.a Layout (Grid, StackLayout, etc)

Comment: Oh, okay thank you!